# Facebook Lint/Debugger 403 and 503 Response code. (Wordpress site.)

Tags: facebook, wordpress, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api

Humbly asking for any assistance people have time to give me on this one. Let me start by saying that I am aware there are previous questions about this on this site and elsewhere on the web; I have read a lot of them, and they are either unanswered/resolved, had a particular cause that doesn't apply to me, or suggests things I have already done.

Over the past few days, Facebook has suddenly stopped scraping my website posts successfully, so when I paste a link into Facebook it pulls nothing through - no thumb or description.  I run the links through the FB lint/debugger, and it alternates between 403 and 503 response codes, but mainly 403. Previous links that Facebook has cached/successfully scraped still display with thumbs and desc, but still present as a 403 or 503 response.

My site is http://21stcenturyburlesque.com
One of the new URLs I have been testing is : http://21stcenturyburlesque.com/the-burlesque-top-50-2013/

- I have checked with the server/host people. Nothing has changed, everything fine.
- I have tried with the default wordpress theme. No change.
- I have read threads about Bullet Proof Security causing issues, although why it suddenly would I don't know. It was deactivated on my site anyway, but I went through the removal process to remove the htaccess file with the BPS code in it. I have then run debug without an htaccess file present, and with a very basic htaccess present. No change.
- Hotlinking protection is disabled in my cpanel.
- I have experimented with adding/removing www. and / when I paste the link into lint as someone suggested. No change.
- I use Facebook OGP Wordpress plugin. I spoke to the creator and he says the plugin is working as it should and to contact my host/server. See bullet one.
- I tried creating a new FB App and using the new App Id number with the OGP plugin. No change.
- Checked the cpanel error log. This came up three times tonight: 
  [Fri Nov 01 21:47:53 2013] [error] [client 193.242.149.35] File does not exist: /home/****/public_html/403.shtml
- There are a few other things I ruled out but I've been at this for so long I can't remember all of them, so if someone suggests something else I've tried then I apologise for not mentioning it here in advance.

If anyone can suggest anything else, I would really appreciate it. I manage to fix most technical problems I come up against, but this has stumped me and my much more experienced colleague and it is really affecting my clickthrough rates and site traffic. If it comes down to adding things to my htaccess file, I would appreciate guidance on what to add/remove. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: to rule out Wordpress as a problem, can you upload a file into the root of your directory called test.php then call that in the FB Linter and see if you still get a 403 error

Comment: I ran it through the debugger and it came back with a 404. The file is definitely there though - when I click the 'fetched url' it's there.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your htaccess file?

Comment: yes, use www.pastebin.com and the paste the link here

Comment: Can you try replacing this "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]" with this "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]"  

If you read the comment above that line, it says that it is used to block bots from making HEAD requests which I assume that is what Facebook does when it crawls the site from the linter.  Taking out this "HEAD" from that line, should hopefully allow Facebook to successfully crawl the page.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: ok, last try: take out "TRACE" from that list as well, so the line should now read: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]"

Comment: Oh well. My next step would be to test it without the .htaccess there at all to verify that the problem is not on the server.  If you remove the .htaccess and FB can then access the test.php URL correctly, we'll know that problem is inside the .htaccess.  However, if you take your htaccess down, your whole site will go down as Wordpress depends on that.  It might be worth setting up a test domain and point it to the same server so you can check.

Comment: Ok hang on, my mistake, let me show you the actual current htaccess, I've revelaed the hidden file now. Will delete the above.

Comment: Ok, THIS is the current htaccess file - turns out I had two in there and this is the current one: http://pastebin.com/B2h5hhyG

Comment: hm ok, can't see anything in there. What I would do now is set up a new subdomain, point it to the same server but a different document root, upload a test php file, run it through the FB Linter and see if you get the same result. That will tell you whether the problem lies within the .htaccess or is linked to something weird with the PHP setup or something else. Your hosting company might be able to help you get a test subdomain set up.

Comment: I have another subdomain/website on this server, and FB can't seem to scrape urls from that one either. Hosting/Server people say nothing has changed on their end though. Today I found that one of my new posts, if the / at the end is removed, still has a 403 in debug but does pull information through when pasted into FB. Only works for that one link though, not for any other new test posts or pages I publish.

Comment: I'd setup a new subdomain server for testing with only one single PHP file there.  That will rule out for sure wordpress or htaccess as a problem and would indicate possibly the blame is with the apache config or PHP config...

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Drove me crazy for hours (maybe days). In your FB app settings make sure that the top Facebook url has **http://**

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'top Facebook URL'. Could you clarify?

Comment: I added a picture to my answer.

Comment: Ah ok. My site URL does have http, yes.  I don't have anything entered under app domains.